# difference between address of pointer to char and pointer to pointer to char

Tags: c, pointers

I have following sample of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *text[2];
   text[0] = "Hello";
   text[1] = "World";

   printf("Address of text[0]: %p\n", text[0]);
   printf("Address of text   : %p\n", text);

   return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Address of text[0]: 0x400694
Address of text   : 0x7ffcac41b000
```

I am wondering why these addresses differ in length. Why is address of first pointer to char only 6 digits length?

Comment: Firstly, `%p` requires `void *` pointers. Secondly, there's no "difference in length". The first output simply omits leading zeros.

Comment: "`Address of text[0]: %p\n", text[0]` does not print the address of `text[0]`, but the contents.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in "address length", the difference is in the *value*.

In this particular case, I assume the `text[0]` pointer points to a data segment that holds the compile time value `"Hello"`, and the `text` pointer points to a runtime address.

Since these are at different memory segments, they can be "very far" and so you get the output you see.

Answer (score 2):

The first address is the address of "Hello", which is stored in your data segment.

The second address is the address of `text[]`, which is stored in your stack.

These two areas of memory are far from each other, so one has many digits, the other has few digits.

Apparently, `%p` renders only as many digits as necessary to represent the address.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Address of text[0]: %p\n", text[0]);
```

prints the address of C string (the address first element of array points to), while:

```
printf("Address of text   : %p\n", text);
```

prints the address of array's first element.

Answer (score 0):

To get the address of the first item of the array `text`, you'll have to use:

```
printf("Address of text[0]: %p\n", (void *)&text[0]);
```

In your question, you are printing the address of the first character of the string `"Hello"` (in other words, of the *content* of text[0]), not the address of the first element of the array `text`, i.e. not the address ***of*** `text[0]`, just the address stored ***in*** `text[0]`.